# Not able to open email attachment from bytes array

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to attach a binary data retrieved from MySQL server to an email as attachment using VB.net.

I can send out a email with attachment but not able to open any of the attachment file even word file also is empty.

The error message is --> Adobe Reader could not open "xxx.pdf" because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Been googled around but still not able to find out what is wrong with my code.

Anyone can help will be very appreciated!Thanks!

```
    Dim m_ImageBinary As [Byte]() = New [Byte](-1) {}
    Dim m_AttachmentType As String = ""
    Dim m_AttachmentName As String = ""
    Dim m_Attachment As Boolean = False
    Dim cmd3 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Attachment, AttachmentType, AttachmentName FROM tbcommunication WHERE CommunicationID = " & cid, MySql)
    Dim rdr2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
    While rdr2.Read()
        If rdr2("Attachment").ToString() <> "" Then
            Dim m_Length As Integer = DirectCast(rdr2("Attachment"), [Byte]()).Length

            m_ImageBinary = New [Byte](m_Length - 1) {}
            m_ImageBinary = DirectCast(rdr2("Attachment"), [Byte]())
            m_AttachmentType = rdr2("AttachmentType").ToString()
            m_AttachmentName = rdr2("AttachmentName").ToString()
        End If
    End While

    If m_ImageBinary.Length <> 0 Then
        If m_Attachment = False Then
            If m_AttachmentType.Contains("jpeg") OrElse m_AttachmentType.Contains("bmp") OrElse m_AttachmentType.Contains("gif") Then
                m_Attachment = False
            Else
                m_Attachment = True
            End If
        End If

        If m_Attachment = True Then
            ' If not image file
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & m_Atta`enter code here`chmentName)
        End If

        'Write(binary)
        'Response.ContentType = m_AttachmentType
        'Response.BinaryWrite(m_ImageBinary)
        'Response.[End]()
    End If



    Dim mailmssg As New MailMessage()
    Dim smtp_client As New SmtpClient

    Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim bytes As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()

        Dim att As New Attachment(New MemoryStream(bytes), m_AttachmentName)

        mailmssg.Attachments.Add(att)
        MemoryStream.Dispose()

        smtp_client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        smtp_client.Send(mailmssg)
   End Using
```

Comment: Have you inspected the resulting attachment with a hex editor to see if anything is obviously wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
'...
' memoryStream = new blank MemoryStream
Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        ' get emtpy array from memoryStream
        Dim bytes As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()
        ' Create empty MemoryStream from empty bytes array
        Dim att As New Attachment(New MemoryStream(bytes), m_AttachmentName)
'...
```

With your current code you'll never send anything than an empty file with a name and always only one.

Comment: owhh..david can you guide me some hints..really no idea on the memorystream indeed..